# 'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found work with Parse

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform

I am working with Parse and Facebook I have the following 2 errors:

> 1. `'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found`
> 2. `Failed to import bridging header`

I already imported both `ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h` and `ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h` to my bridging-header because I am doing everything with Swift.

But when I just used Parse everything working fine, so I think the problem is only with `FacebookSDK`.

after I installed pod file and start project here are my files:

1. this is my app delegate

   import UIKit

   @UIApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   ```
   var window: UIWindow?

   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.

       Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

       // Initialize Parse.
       Parse.setApplicationId(“MY_APLLICATION_ID”,
           clientKey: "MY_APLLICATION_KEY")
       PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
       // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
       PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)



       return true
   }

   func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
       // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
       // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
   }

   func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
       // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
       // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
   }

   func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
       // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
   }

   func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
       // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
       FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
   }

   func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
       // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
   }

   func application(application: UIApplication,
       openURL url: NSURL,
       sourceApplication: String?,
       annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
           return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
               openURL: url,
               sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
               annotation: annotation)
   }
   ```

   }
2. viewController

   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       var permissions = ["public_profile"]

       PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
           (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
           if let user = user {
               if user.isNew {
                   println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
               } else {
                   println("User logged in through Facebook!")
               }
           } else {
               println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
           }
       }

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
   ```

   }

plist

I added this

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>MY_APP_KEY</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>MY_APP_KEY</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>MY_APP_NAME</string>
```

4 my bridging-file

```
#import "FBSDKCoreKit.h"
#import "Parse.h"
```

Comment: You have not mentioned you were using `ParseFacebookUtilsV4` in your `Podfile`. I suspect you have multiple conflicting libraries.

Comment: What should I do, I think I can not avoid using ParseFacebookUtilsV4?

Comment: If an answer is useful to you, you may want to tick *This answer is useful* in order to let others know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Facebook SDK Swift Integration

It is likely that one of the many steps involved with this task may have gone wrong. If you start over from a fresh project, you will likely find out what step you missed. Follow the F**acebook iOS Integration Tutorial** below.

## Create a fresh new Xcode project

Xcode > File > Project... > Single View Application > Next > Product Name `SO-32302877`, Language **Swift** > Next > Create.

**Add a pod**

In terminal:

```
cd SO-32302877
pod init
```

and make your **Podfile** like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'SO-32302877' do
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
end
```

Close Xcode project if not already done. In Terminal, run:

```
pod install
```

## Import the SDK

Open `SO-32302877.xcworkspace`. Create a bridging header. Simplest way is to add & delete an Obj-C file. In Xcode > Navigator, select the `SO-32302877` group, Xcode > File > New > File... > Cocoa Touch Class > Next > Class: ObjC, Language: **Objective-C** > Next > Create.

[image]

You can now select and delete the `ObjC.h` and `ObjC.m` files from Xcode and *Move to Trash*. You now have a `SO-32302877-Bridging-Header.h`, and the target `SO-32302877` **Build Settings** are set up properly.
In `SO-32302877-Bridging-Header.h`, add:

```
#import "FBSDKCoreKit.h"
```

## Test Instrumentation

In your **Swift** implementation, invoke:

```
let token:FBSDKAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken(
    tokenString: "tokenString",
    permissions: [],
    declinedPermissions: [],
    appID: "appID",
    userID: "userID",
    expirationDate: NSDate(),
    refreshDate: NSDate())
print("\(token)")
```

Built, linked, ran & tested on Xcode 7 + iOS 8.4.

---

*To download the full project, search for [SO-32302877](http://swiftarchitect.com/) in Swift Recipes.*

Comment: you did not understand the question, right? Your way only how to work with Facebook. and After I imported parse I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

## Facebook + Parse + Utils

*Using ParseFacebookUtilsV4 to match the code in the question. I suspect you are experiencing difficulties because of multiple, incoherent libraries.*

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'SO-32302877' do
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
end
```

**SO-32302877-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "FBSDKCoreKit.h"
#import "Parse.h"
#import "PFFacebookUtils.h"
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
                     [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    Parse.setApplicationId("applicationId", clientKey: "clientKey")
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook(applicationLaunchOptions: launchOptions)
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpened(launchOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}
```

**View Controller**

```
let permissions = ["permissions"]
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) {
    (user: PFUser?, error:Error?) in
    if let user = user {
        print("user.isNew \(user.isNew)")
    } else {
        print("!user")
    }
}
```

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-32302877) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-32302877).

Comment: OK, I tried again. Now a new problem"FBSDKCoreKit.h" file not found

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using, and do you have the latest Cocoapods?

Comment: If you modify the `Podfile`, you may want to `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install` instead of just `pod install`. Make sure you close Xcode to avoid .workspace errors, and `Clean Build Folder`.

Comment: still nothing, i am trying. But still no result

Comment: Did you download the Swift Recipe? It works out of the box. Do you have en error with `pod install`?

Comment: I followed both of your tutorials and posted whole my code and problem. No problem with pod and I did everything that Parse and Facebook API suggested but none were successful. I am just having a bad time with it.